# moment.js Appcelerator changing the language of the date format

Tags: appcelerator, momentjs

I have implemented a scrollable view, each view having views with a heading, date and time (in a specific format) and a language.
I want to display the date and time in the language I am mentioning below as well as update the local time of that country, say, the date and time have been displayed in German, so the date and the time to be displayed should be of Germany's time zone. but I can't seem to do so. Any suggestions why?

This is my .xml file

```
  <Alloy>
        <View class="container">
            <View class="titleClass">
                <Label class="titleLabelClass" backgroundColor="yellow" top="5%" onClick="nextController">moment.js Example</Label>
            </View>
            <ScrollableView class ="scrollableClass" backgroundColor="gray">
                <View>
                    <Label class = "info1">Displaying Date and Language using moment.js Library</Label>
                    <Label class="dateClass1" id="dateIdScroll1"></Label>
                    <Label class="languageClass1" id="langIDScroll1"></Label>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Label class = "info2">Displaying Date and Language using moment.js Library</Label>
                    <Label class="dateClass2" id="dateIdScroll2"></Label>
                    <Label class="languageClass2" id="langIDScroll2"></Label>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Label class = "info3">Displaying Date and Language using moment.js Library</Label>
                    <Label class="dateClass3" id="dateIdScroll3"></Label>
                    <Label class="languageClass3" id="langIDScroll3"></Label>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Label class = "info4">Displaying Date and Language using moment.js Library</Label>
                    <Label class="dateClass4" id="dateIdScroll4"></Label>
                    <Label class="languageClass4" id="langIDScroll4"></Label>
                </View>
            </ScrollableView>
        </View>
        <View class="dateTimeFormatClass1" layout="horizontal" top="20%" backgroundColor="yellow">
            <Label class="formatClass1" id="format1"></Label>
            <Label class="changedFormatClass1" id="changedFormat1"></Label>
        </View>
        <View class="dateTimeFormatClass2" layout="horizontal">
            <Label class="formatClass2" id="format2"></Label>
            <Label class="changedFormatClass2" id="changedFormat2"></Label>
        </View>
        <View class="dateTimeFormatClass3" layout="horizontal">
            <Label class="formatClass3" id="format3"></Label>
            <Label class="changedFormatClass3" id="changedFormat3"></Label>
        </View>
            <!-- <View top="30%" backgroundColor="yellow">
                <Button class="nextClass" onClick="nextController" top="5%" backgroundColor="red" title="next"></Button>
            </View> -->
    </Alloy>
```

This is my .js file

```
var args = $.args;
var moment = require("alloy/moment");
// moment().format();
function nextController(e) {
    var next = Alloy.createController('listviewPOC').getView();
    Alloy.Globals.parent.add(next);
}

function showTime() {
    $.dateIdScroll1.text = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $.langIDScroll1.text = moment().locale("en");
    $.dateIdScroll2.text = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $.langIDScroll2.text = moment().locale();
    $.dateIdScroll3.text = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $.langIDScroll3.text = moment().locale();
    $.dateIdScroll4.text = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $.langIDScroll4.text = moment().locale();
}
showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 500);
```

Comment: I don't know enough about appcelerator, anyway do you need to show results in German locale or in Germany's time zone? Note that moment by default uses local time (and supports UTC), if you need to support different timezones you can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: I wish to display different time zones in their respective languages in different views of the scrollable view. First view will have the local timezone and the language english, second will have the time zone of Germany and this will be in the language german. Accordingly the next two views will be filled but in different timezones and their respective languages

Answer (score 1):

First, set the moment.js lib to your desired locale.  You can do this in alloy.js:

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment');
moment.locale('de');
```

Or if you want your app to set it automatically:

`moment.locale(Ti.Locale.currentLanguage);`

After that, you will want to use the [localized format tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) whenever possible.

So

`$.dateIdScroll1.text = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');`

Would turn into something like:

`$.dateIdScroll1.text = moment().format('LLLL');`

If you need to tweak or modify a locale, check out the [customization section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/)

Comment: Hi Adam! The method mentioned above is yet not changing the language of the date and time that the view displays.. Can you guide me through this?